# error running mongodb on windows 7 (32)....!

Tags: mongodb

i have installed 32 bit version of MongoDB, and also the windows 7 hotfix(273128) but when i run "mongod" command it will give the following error[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvtqH.png)

how can i specify "storage engine explicity" and what's  this ?

Comment: Please include the error directly in the question, as text. Not as a linked picture.

Comment: And reading it might help, too: "Please [specify a storage engine explicitly](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine)." ;)

Comment: how can i specify "storage engine explicity" and what's this ?

Comment: thanks my issue is resolved